# Вставить пробел после цифр

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения, replace

Ранее написал валидацию для замены пробелов в строке, что бы валидацию проходило только определенное количество цифр, сейчас же нужно что бы после цифр автоматически вставлялся пробел (пришло 12b, заменил на 12 b)

```
Validation.add('number-validation', '', function(v) {
var vReplace = v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(vReplace) || /^[0-9]{19,19}$/.test(vReplace);});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var string = '12b 14d',
result = string.replace(/(\d+)/g, '$1 ');

console.log(result); // > 12 b 14 d
```

Подробнее: [Наборы и диапазоны](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges)

Comment: Но ведь этот код добавит пробел после любого числа, не только перед не-пробелом: `12 16` => "12  16 ".

Comment: @stribizhev как вариант: `string.replace(/(\d+)/g, '$1 ').replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')`. Хотя, судя по задачи автора таких случаев у него не планируется.

Comment: Да, это я просто так придираюсь :) Я бы использовал в другом случае [`.replace(/\d(?![\s\d]|$)/g, '$&')`](https://regex101.com/r/uO9hL3/1).

Comment: Вариант с заменой лишнего пробела хорошо и уменьшает количество проблем которые могут быть потом.